# How to get the values selected in each spinner?

Tags: android

I have a dialog that ask for input, the input from this dialog is used to created multiple spinners ...I want to be able to display the items selected in these spinners

Answer (score 0):

```
Spinner spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner);
String text = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
```

Comment: i have used getSelectedItem().toString();but its only giving me the value of the spinner i selected last...What i want is the all the value of the spinners

Comment: So...every time an item is selected within the `Spinner` you must call the code above and save it into an `array`.

Comment: grade.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

            public void onItemSelected(final AdapterView<?> parent, View cview, final int cpos, long cid) {




            }

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is you may be declaring you spinner one time and initialize it multiple time when  dialog is showing. So your spinners are same object. When you choose one after another it give list value you choose.

share you code how you implement them then i can solve your problem easily.